# "Ambiguous attribute key" error after updating to terraform version 0.12.26

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

After terraform version update from 0.11 to 0.12.26, I'm seeing error with lookup and list of values inside map.

```
variable "foo" {
  type = map
}


foo = {
  x.y = "bar"
}
```

I have a map "foo" as variable type (map) and then i have key-value pair in map with x.y = "bar". In lookup, I'm trying to read value of x.y as,

```
lookup(var.foo, x.y)
```

with this, I'm getting error,

```
Error: Ambiguous attribute key

  on line 13:
  13:   x.y = "bar"

If this expression is intended to be a reference, wrap it in parentheses. If
it's instead intended as a literal name containing periods, wrap it in quotes
to create a string literal.
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a map key that contains a dot character `.` then you must write the key in quotes, so Terraform can see that you intend to produce a string containing a dot rather than to use the value of the `y` attribute of variable `x`:

```
foo = {
  "x.y" = "bar"
}
```

Likewise, to access that element you'll need to quote the key in the index expression, like `foo["x.y"]`. You could also potentially use `lookup(foo, "x.y")` -- still with the quotes -- but that approach is deprecated in Terraform 0.12 because `foo["x.y"]` has replaced it as the main way to access an element from a map value.

Comment: @Meet101 this answer is correct and you should accept it and upvote it.